# Strange behaviour with new sendmail.cf

Tags: configuration, sendmail

I am trying to change my sendmail configuration to deliver all "user unknown" emails to a specific account (baduser).
I added the DL definition to sendmail.mc and generated test.cf.
Then I tested this new config using:

echo who | sendmail -v -Ctest.cf noone

and the email was correctly delivered to the defined account.

I then renamed test.cf to sendmail.cf (in /etc/mail) and retested with:

echo what | sendmail -Csendmail.cf noone

and again the email was delivered to the baduser account.

Happy with this, I then restarted sendmail (via systemctl) and sent yet another email to an invalid account.

Instead of the email being delivered to baduser, I received a 550 5.1.1 user unknown reject email.

What have I missed here.

(Fedora 22 & sendmail 8.14.7/8.13.3)

Here are the log entries for a reject.

Nov 27 09:59:19 server sendmail[46243]: tAQNTJQH046243: from=scldad, size=4, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201511262329.tAQNTJQH046243@server.benparts.com.au>, relay=scldad@localhost

Nov 27 09:59:19 server sendmail[46243]: tAQNTJQH046243: to=noone, ctladdr=scldad (1000/1000), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30004, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown

```
-v -i log:

No domain:

[scldad@server ~]$ (echo subject: test; echo) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -v -i noone
noone... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
220 server.benparts.com.au ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.7/8.13.3; Sat, 28 Nov 2015 13:29:02 +1030
>>> EHLO server.benparts.com.au
250-server.benparts.com.au Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-EXPN
250-VERB
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
>>> VERB
250 2.0.0 Verbose mode
>>> MAIL From:<scldad@server.benparts.com.au> SIZE=15
250 2.1.0 <scldad@server.benparts.com.au>... Sender ok
>>> RCPT To:<noone@server.benparts.com.au>
>>> DATA
550 5.1.1 <noone@server.benparts.com.au>... User unknown
503 5.0.0 Need RCPT (recipient)
>>> RSET
250 2.0.0 Reset state
/home/scldad/dead.letter... Saved message in /home/scldad/dead.letter
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 server.benparts.com.au closing connection

With domain:

[scldad@server ~]$ (echo subject: test; echo) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -v -i noone@benparts.com.au
noone@benparts.com.au... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
220 server.benparts.com.au ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.7/8.13.3; Sat, 28 Nov 2015 13:27:38 +1030
>>> EHLO server.benparts.com.au
250-server.benparts.com.au Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-EXPN
250-VERB
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
>>> VERB
250 2.0.0 Verbose mode
>>> MAIL From:<scldad@server.benparts.com.au> SIZE=15
250 2.1.0 <scldad@server.benparts.com.au>... Sender ok
>>> RCPT To:<noone@benparts.com.au>
>>> DATA
550 5.1.1 <noone@benparts.com.au>... User unknown
503 5.0.0 Need RCPT (recipient)
>>> RSET
250 2.0.0 Reset state
/home/scldad/dead.letter... Saved message in /home/scldad/dead.letter
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 server.benparts.com.au closing connection

As root:

[root@server ~]# (echo subject: test; echo) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -v -i noone
noone... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
220 server.benparts.com.au ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.7/8.13.3; Sat, 28 Nov 2015 13:30:00 +1030
>>> EHLO server.benparts.com.au
250-server.benparts.com.au Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-EXPN
250-VERB
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
>>> VERB
250 2.0.0 Verbose mode
>>> MAIL From:<scldad@server.benparts.com.au> SIZE=15
250 2.1.0 <scldad@server.benparts.com.au>... Sender ok
>>> RCPT To:<noone@server.benparts.com.au>
>>> DATA
550 5.1.1 <noone@server.benparts.com.au>... User unknown
503 5.0.0 Need RCPT (recipient)
>>> RSET
250 2.0.0 Reset state
>>> RSET
250 2.0.0 Reset state
scldad... Using cached ESMTP connection to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
>>> MAIL From:<> SIZE=1039
250 2.1.0 <>... Sender ok
>>> RCPT To:<scldad@server.benparts.com.au>
>>> DATA
250 2.1.5 <scldad@server.benparts.com.au>... Recipient ok
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
>>> .
050 <scldad@server.benparts.com.au>... Connecting to local...
050 <scldad@server.benparts.com.au>... Sent
250 2.0.0 tAS300jh034101 Message accepted for delivery
scldad... Sent (tAS300jh034101 Message accepted for delivery)
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 server.benparts.com.au closing connection
```

Comment: Repeat the tests. Execute `sendmail -bv noone` as root.

Comment: sendmail -bv noone gives the correct result: delivery to baduser. However, any "real" attempt to send to noone still gets reject bounce.

Comment: Could you include log entries generated by rejected recipieint?

Comment: Log entries added to original post.

Comment: Your SMTP server (sendmail controlled by sendmail.cf) expects `user@domain` addresses.  Your sendmail controlled by submit.cf seems to send "domain less" recipient address.  Can you send a test message in verbose mode AS NON ROOT USER? `(echo subject: test; echo) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -v -i noone`

Comment: I get the same reject bounce if I send from another domain so I do not think it is caused by submit.cf.

Comment: Execute `sendmail -bv noone@benparts.com.au` as root.

Comment: noone@benparts.com.au... deliverable: mailer local, host noone, user baduser